# last zeros gets stripped when use php minus calculation

Tags: php

I'm using minus php query to calculate and find out two variables difference. Here is the code i'm using to calculate

Example

```
$v1="13.240";
$v2="0";
echo $v1 - $v2;
```

When calculation gets completed, the zero at the end of variable gets stripped eg (13.24), which in right scenario should have been 13.240. I do not understand how to fix this issue.

Comment: You cant do math on strings to it is converting to an integer, `13.24` and `13.240` are the same as integers. You could add trailing zeros.

Comment: @user3783243 Since when was 13.24 an integer?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular In general terms, I guess if you're analyzing ever term `str_replace('integer', 'float', $my_comment)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are same, but if you need that badly, then you can use `number_format()` to keep number 3 decimal places,

```
<?php
$v1="13.240";
$v2="0";
echo number_format($v1 - $v2, 3);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/FV1Or